# promise change global variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I am trying to do some benchmarking on different style of javascript code, here is what I have:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var timer = function(name) {
    var start = new Date();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            var end  = new Date();
            var time = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            console.log('Function:', name, 'finished in', time, 'ms');
        }
    };
};

function regular (a, cb) {
    if (a % 2 === 0) return cb(null, a);
    return cb(a);
}

function promise (a) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        if (a % 2 === 0) resolve(a);
        else reject(a);
    });
}


var t = timer('regular');
var g = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    regular(i, function(odd, even) {
        if (odd) g = g + (odd * 2);
        else g = g + (even * 3);
    });
}
console.log('g:', g); // g: 125015000
t.stop();

var t2 = timer('promise');
var h = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    promise(i).then(function(x) {h = h + (x*3);}).catch(function(x) {h = h + (x*2);});
}
console.log('h:', h); // h: 0
t2.stop();
```

What interesting is, the promises doesn't change the global variable 'h', how can I make it return the same result as variable 'g'?

**UPDATE**

Here is changed code that try to get the final result, but the non-deterministic of promises give us unexpected result.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    promise(i).then(function(x) {
        h = h + (x*3); if (x===10000) console.log('h:', h);
    }).catch(function(x) {h = h + (x*2);}); // h: 75015000 
}
```

Currently my code that give the expected output is even stranger.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    promise(i).then(function(x) {
        h = h + (x*3);
    }).catch(function(x) {
        h = h + (x*2);
        if (x===9999) console.log('h:', h);  // <- attention here
    }); // h: 125015000
}
```

Can anyone show me a better code and explain the code above? (The code above shows the deterministic correct result when i is 9999 not 10000)

Comment: You are using multiple, non-sequenced promises which means they could run in an unpredictable order.  And, you're using them for synchronous operations.  None of this really makes sense and certainly does not describe a practical real-world use of promises.  I'd rather see the real problem you're trying to solve or advise you to not use promises here at all.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00. But since you're asking: your variable `h` **is** updated, but `console.log('h:', h);` gets executed (asynchronously) before all those promises have executed. You can see this with `setTimeout(function() { console.log('h:', h); }, 2000);`

Comment: @Viktor Can you show us a example to get the result **right after** the computation?

Comment: @jfriend00 this is just a abstracted problem that people may face in the near future, the non-sequential of the promises execution is not a issue to return the correct final result.

Comment: answered your original question for why the `console.log()` wasn't showing the final value of `h`.  Asking further questions about promises that only use synchronous code seems a bit pointless to me since you shouldn't even use promises with code that is always synchronous as they are just a waste of time, unnecessary complexity and slower performance than just using plain synchronous function calls.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is not waste of time, it is an experiment. Both are async, but results are vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem with promises you can wrap all the `then` methods with `reduce` and listen to all Promises finish, this is running the promises sequentially.

if you like you can use also `Promise.all()` to run in all the promises in parallel.

```js
function promise (a) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        if (a % 2 === 0) resolve(a);
        else reject(a);
    });
};

var timer = function(name) {
    var start = new Date();
    return {
        stop: function() {
            var end  = new Date();
            var time = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            console.log('Function:', name, 'finished in', time, 'ms');
        }
    };
};

console.log('Right result', Array.from({length : 10000}, (el, i)=> (i + 1) % 2 === 0 ? (i+1)*3 : (i+1)*2).reduce((a,b)=> a + b));

var t2 = timer('promise');
var h = 0;
Promise.all(Array.from({length : 10000}, (el, i)=> promise(i + 1).then(x =>{ h += x*3}).catch(x =>{ h += x*2 })
))
.then(()=>{
  console.log('h:', h);
  t2.stop();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, can you show me the Promise.all() version?

Comment: @nobody Use Promise.all() like this, the previous approach with reduce not worked, because the last item (Promise) in the array is never called with then method and output is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Promises ALWAYS call their `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers asynchronously.  Even if they are resolved immediately, they will let the current thread of JS finish executing and will call the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers asynchronously on the "next tick".

Thus your `console.log('h:', h);` is executed BEFORE any of then `.then()` handlers from the loop have been called.  If you put the `console.log()` statement inside the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers, you will find they are getting called, but AFTER your `console.log('h:', h);` is called.

Promises are designed to be an asynchronous interface.  And, it's very important that an asynchronous interface is always consistent so even if the promise is resolved synchronously, they still call their `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers asynchronously on the next tick so that they are always consistent and the developer using them doesn't need to worry about sometimes getting an async response and sometimes getting a sync response.  Instead, they are always async responses.

As I said in my comment, any real world coding situation should only use promises for operations that are at least sometimes asynchronous.  If your operation is always synchronous (as your above example is), then they should not use promises because promises just make synchronous operations more complicated than just using straight synchronous function calls.

In addition, your multiple promise operations in your loop are not sequenced or coordinated in any given way.  If these were real async operations, they could complete in any order and your updating of the `h` variable would have an uncertain order (which is often a problem and thus is usually a bad design pattern).

Comment: even if the non-sequenced promises should also return the same result for deterministic computation. In the benchmark example, the sequence doesn't matter, the result is. Determine the end of async operation in promise is essential.

Comment: @nobody - But with no sequencing, you have no way to know when the last one is done and thus no way to get the final result.  In a real world situation, you would likely have to have some coordination among your promises to at least know when the last one is done.  Abstract or hypothetical questions like this don't work that well here on stack overflow because of these very situations.  It's much better to ask a real world question with real world code where we can avoid abstract debates and discuss real world problems/solutions.  It's a lot easier to offer a precise answer to a real problem.

Comment: @nobody - When you fire off a bunch of promises in parallel, you should NEVER make any assumptions about what order they will complete in.  If they are real async operations, they could finish in any order.

Comment: @nobody - Do my first two paragraphs explain why your original `console.log()` did not see the result?  Does that answer your original question?

Comment: Kindly check out the edited code, seems like your accusation of **bad design pattern** doesn't stand. The original question is returning the promises result as same as the callback version. Kindly provide a snippet of code.

Comment: @nobody - I don't understand what you're asking.  Your operations are actually synchronous so the order happens to be deterministic and thus there is no reason to use promises at all.  If your operations were actually asynchronous, then the order would not be deterministic at all and this design would simply be wrong.  It might work sometimes, but that would be pure luck.  It would not be reliable.  If you want to know when ALL async operations in a group are done, you collect all the promises in an array and use `Promise.all(array).then()` to know when all the promises are done.

Comment: @nobody - Or you can precisely sequence the promises so one happens after the other and then you know the exact order they will be run in.

Comment: The deterministic result **does** coming out from the promises, not pure luck, did you try out my code? It shows that even asynchronous in charge, deterministic value will return at some point no matter how far it go.

Comment: @nobody - OK, you go right ahead and code that way. I've given you some good advice.  If you choose to ignore it, that's your prerogative.  This is not how you use promises and not the kind of situation you use promises for.  I'm done explaining that to you because you only seem to care that your code happens to work in this specific case even though it's a poor design pattern that won't work in most other cases.  Never mind - I've said my piece.

Comment: Thanks for your piece.